# run/debug application in Intellij-idea with gradle "compileOnly" project-type dependency

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I have 2 sub-projects/modules in my gradle project. one is a plain jar (let's call it libApp), the 2nd is an executable spring-boot application (let's call it execApp). I normally build execApp  with "bootjar" gradle task but because **I don't want to include libApp in execApp's fat/uber jar**, so in my gradle.build, the libApp dependency is defined as:

```
compileOnly project(':libApp')
```

I normally launch execApp inside Intellij by right-clicking execApp's main class and choosing "debug 'execAppMainClass'".
However when execApp calls a class part of libApp, I get a ClassNotFoundException.

Hence my question is:
How can I prevent libApp from being part of the fat jar created by "bootjar" task while still being able to debug my application in Intellij ?

Note1: using gradle 6.6.1 with Idea 2020.3.2
Note2: Intellij's setting for gradle is set to: "build and run using: Gradle"
Note3: in Intellij's Run/Debug configuration, I tried to set "include dependencies with 'provided' scope" but that didn't seem to make any difference (still getting ClassNotFoundException)

SAMPLE PROJECT:
a) download https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/  and import into Intellij
b) in application module replace "implementation project(':library')" with "compileOnly project(':library')"
c) inside Intellij, right-click DemoApplication class, and choose "Debug DemoApplication.main()".
d) you get ClassNotFoundException: com.example.multimodule.service.MyService

thanks a lot in advance for your expertise and your time.

Best Regards

Comment: Cannot reproduce: when I set a project `compileOnly` dependency - it is added with the **provided** scope to the main module and if I and enable **include dependencies with 'provided' scope** it works for me - the classes are found at runtime from the `:libApp` project dependency. Can you provide a sample project?

Comment: @Andrey I've added a sample project (straight from spring.io)

Comment: Cannot reproduce. See https://monosnap.com/file/noy8mw7uqLc7sZquMndSdvJMYqoFIb There are two projects: `complete` and `initial` - make sure you are running the correct one. Also make sure you run **Reload** action in Gradle tool window. If you can compile a reproducible project with the steps, file a bug attaching it an describing the exact steps at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: @Andrey thanks a lot for your feedback! I made sure to reload the project from Gradle but that didn't change anything unfortunately. As per your screenshot, the library dependency is listed as "provided" for me as well. But even if I flag 'include dependencies with "provided" scope' in the run/debug configuration, the execution fails with a ClassNotFoundException.